# How to get the firebase document ID inside my object when using ngxs-lab/firestore-plugin

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ngxs

I'm using NGXS for my state management and also using the firestore-plugin(https://github.com/ngxs-labs/firestore-plugin).

How do I add the id of the document inside my object?

I've created my store:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxsFirestore } from '@ngxs-labs/firestore-plugin';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SpotsFirestore extends NgxsFirestore<Spot> {
  protected path = 'seasons/2021/spots';
}
```

I've created my state&actions:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Emitted, NgxsFirestoreConnect, StreamEmitted } from '@ngxs-labs/firestore-plugin';
import { Action, NgxsOnInit, Selector, State, StateContext } from '@ngxs/store';
import { InitializeSpotsAction } from './spots.actions';
import { SpotsFirestore } from './spots.firestore';

export interface SpotsStateModel {
  spots: Spot[];
}

@State<SpotsStateModel>({
  name: 'spots',
  defaults: {
    spots: [],
  },
})
@Injectable()
export class SpotsState implements NgxsOnInit {
  @Selector()
  static spots(state: SpotsStateModel) {
    return state.spots;
  }

  constructor(private spotsFireStore: SpotsFirestore, private ngxsFirestoreConnect: NgxsFirestoreConnect) {}
  ngxsOnInit(ctx?: StateContext<any>) {
    this.ngxsFirestoreConnect.connect(InitializeSpotsAction, {
      to: (action) => this.spotsFireStore.collection$(),
    });
  }

  @Action(StreamEmitted(InitializeSpotsAction))
  getAllEmitted(ctx: StateContext<SpotsStateModel>, { action, payload }: Emitted<InitializeSpotsAction, Spot[]>) {
    ctx.patchState({ spots: payload });
  }
}
```

and my model looks like this:

```
interface Spot {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  checkinValue: number;
  imageUrl: string;
  coordinates: firebase.firestore.GeoPoint;
}
```

so obviously, id isn't inside my firebase document but is identifying it. But it will definitely be usefull for me to have it.

I guess I should override something in NgxsFirestore, but I can't figure out what on how?
Is it mandatory to have it inside the document?

Comment: Is the id: string; in interface Spot the same as the Firebase document ID? Do you need it inside your model? Why do you think it will definitely be usefull for you to have it?

Comment: Because I want to have Url like `/spots/{id}/edit`, `/spots/{id}/comments`, ... so what else would I put here(that would allow me to retrieve it from firebase with ngxs)

Comment: Each Firebase document has a name, which was given upon creation. You could use this name as id: String, name being sufficient, together with collection name, to retrieve your stored object.

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
// asynchronously retrieve the document
ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future = docRef.get();
// ...
// future.get() blocks on response
DocumentSnapshot document = future.get();
```
This is documented in [Get data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).

Comment: Relevant code samples are to be found on [googleapis / java-firestore](https://github.com/googleapis/java-firestore/blob/37da386875d1b65121e8a9a92b1a000537f07625/samples/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/firestore/snippets/RetrieveDataSnippets.java#L70-L80).

Comment: @George Yes I know, but my question is how, with NgxsFirestore, I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can! You just need create a property in your service called `idField` like shown bellow:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxsFirestore } from '@ngxs-labs/firestore-plugin';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SpotsFirestore extends NgxsFirestore<Spot> {
  protected path = 'seasons/2021/spots';
  idField = 'spotId'
}
```

In this case, it will add the DocumentId under the property `spotId`

reference: https://github.com/ngxs-labs/firestore-plugin